# Wrapping an element inside a new element right where it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a content which contains many TextNodes, paragraphs and images. I want to put all the images tag inside a parent div. Well, I think there is no direct way to do this (in jQuery, I mean). How should I approach such displacement of elements. The following example illustrates my intent:

Original Content:

```
<div id='content'>
  Here are some texts.
  A second line.
  <a href='http://google.com'>Click Here!</a>
  Another Line.
  <img src='image.jpg' />
  Another another line.
  <img src='secondImage.jpg' />
  Last line and many more to come.
</div>
```

After it is processed:

```
<div id='content'>
  Here are some texts.
  A second line.
  <a href='http://google.com'>Click Here!</a>
  Another Line.
  <div class='image-parent'>
    <img src='image.jpg' />
  </div> 
  Another another line.
<div class='image-parent'>
  <img src='secondImage.jpg' />
</div> 
  Last line and many more to come.
</div>
```

The only different is that a new div is wrapping each image, now.

Comment: `$("img").wrap("<div class='image-parent'></div>")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wraping HTML structure around each element.

```js
$("#content > img").wrap("<div class='image-parent'></div>");
```

```css
.image-parent {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content'>
  Here are some texts.
  A second line.
  <a href='http://google.com'>Click Here!</a>
  Another Line.
  <img src='image.jpg' />
  Another another line.
  <img src='secondImage.jpg' />
  Last line and many more to come.
</div>
```